# LWC-base-components-recipes issue, Summer 20' release, assert.js

Tags: lightning-web-components, bug, lightning-base-component, textarea, summer20

I am using textarea base component, this had to go with lots of other dependencies to my org.
Unfortunately after summer 20' release I had to comment out code in assert.js today:

```
export function assert(condition, message) {
    // if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
        if (!condition) {
            throw new Error(message);
        }
    // }
}
```

otherwise all users will see bellow error, any update on that? I assume it's safe to comment this out for now. But I would like to receive some proper update on this bug.

[image]

Comment: Which component are you referring to?

Comment: As mentioned I am using textarea base component.

testarea.js imports TouchScroller by default and uses it in renderedCallback.
TouchScroller itself imports asset and uses it in constructor.

Since it was working totally fine before summer 20' I am not removing any dependencies and I am assuming that this as a new release bug.

Comment: We have the same issue in all of our lwcs... We're using treeData.js which is calling assert.js

Comment: Hi and welcome to all new SFSE users. If you found this question via search and are also affected, please do not add a "me too" answer. You're welcome to comment if you have information to add, or write an answer if you can help solve the problem.